# Why is the average age of Software Engineers less than 33?

Tags: management, hiring

Based on [StackOverflow's survey](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019#demographics), why is the average age of Software Engineers (that participated in the Stack Overflow survey) less than 33?  *All answers need to include citations to ensure this involves more than just opinions.*

I have friends in various industries ranging from Accounting, Law, Medical, 
and Engineering (architects). All of the aforementioned industries, as far as I can tell and from conversations, put significant value in experience.

The longer you are in the industry the better you are compensated and more valued you become, but from looking at tech this doesn't seem to be the case past 40.

I've also seen plenty of ageism in the Software Engineering industry at a relatively young age (~40). Completely opposite for my friends, whereas their career is taking off at that point and their eyeing that partner role in the next 5-10 years.

With the exception of the two rare genius programmers I met (who just happen to be young) with photographic memories, most of the young programmers I've met need a lot of hand holding and baby-sitting to make sure they aren't doing anything terrible.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97783/discussion-on-question-by-confuseddeer-why-is-the-average-age-of-software-engine).

Comment: Because ageism is rampant in this industry. No other reason.

Comment: One thing that you might want to consider is the massive growth the software engineering market is/was experiencing. In just a few short years the world has been digitalised beyond recognition. And with such a young and fast moving job market. The people who go to college for it get picked up quickly. constantly pushing down the average market(considering there will be less older people to reeducate themselves than young people to start in the field).

Comment: closed? booooooo! How is this an opinion based question if the questions was edited to included a comment about citations required in answers? I'm starting to hate StackExchange and now I remember why I stopped coming to the site.

Comment: It's opinion based, because to answer it you'd need to ask everyone in the industry (or a reasonable group anyway) - all SE data shows is what people have answered. on the survey here.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Because they'll move to other IT roles.**

*Software Engineer* is sometimes an entry-level job and people may move to other roles after some years. They become IT architects, IT product managers, IT consultants, etc. A few even switch to non-technical roles, like project managers or Agile coaches.

Even though they are still working in IT, they are less likely to visit StackOverflow and take the survey.

Comment: Agile coache from Software Engineer, when I see that switch I just think they couldn't cut it. Sorry if that's a bit callous and I'll even agree I'm wrong, but I've never met a good agile coach.

Comment: @Didn't realize entry level jobs paid 6-figures, but then again look at anesthesiology with it's $115k entry level pay.

Comment: @ConfusedDeer I'm not saying it's a good transition. ;-) But I only know people where it was the opposite, they weren't good at software engineering and better at coaching.

Comment: @ConfusedDeer I weakened the statements to make clear what I mean. Of course many will stay *Software Engineers*. Still it has impact on the average age.

Comment: Exactly what I first thought of as an answer. I think a senior partner at a law firm would still call them-self a lawyer even if they are managing cases instead of doing the lower level work, but  a manager in IT is much less likely to still call them-self a software developer.

Comment: @cdkMoose Good point, I think your comment in conjunction with Chris' answer nailed it. I didn't want to admit that Software Developer is a low-level entry job, but it seems to meet the criteria doesn't it. Even doctors are still doctors, just NOT a practicing doctor. Credit to Juha Untinen below who kind of said the same thing.

Comment: @ConfusedDeer Everyone ends up transitioning at some point in their career. Anyone can become agile coach if they are very good at it. It doesn't matter what their previous role was. Agile coaching requires only soft skills. You can't say that software engineer will never have the necessary soft skills.

Comment: @jitendragarg I haven't met a knowledgeable agile coach that seemed well verse in their role. I imagine not all Agile coaches are  useless, just the majority that I've met. I'm a certified Agile Scrum Master (won't ever take the role) and just speaking from my experience, most Agile coaches I've met (more than 10) are folks that from my perspective couldn't couldn't cut it as a developer or folks that transitioned very early in their careers to Agile coaches.

Comment: Then you need to look further. I used to write code on a daily basis, as well, till few months ago, even though I transitioned to coaching role few years ago. I won't say I am perfect at either. That's obviously impossible. But being good at two things is certainly possible.

Answer (score 10):

Young workers are preferred because they don't have family and other non-work obligations and thus are willing to dedicate insane amounts of time to the company's projects, and as importantly, they're cheap, contra your suggestion that they're better paid.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, plus, I just updated the question to try to be less opinion based question. I wasn't trying to insinuate that, rather that there is a cap that after 30 or 40 you are at the end of the line, whereas other industries at 40 you are just ramping up to the big money (i.e partner or director)

Comment: In IT, there are very few big money positions beyond 40. Only bigger companies tend to have Architect, Principal Engineer, or CTO positions. Ie. it is very hard to advance to that level compared to how many "regular" software engineers any given company employs. And also, most developers tend to prefer to work as developers. Bigger positions are less about development and more about service design and management, which aren't interesting to most devs I know.

Comment: I've been working in the very low, including some of the extremely low, level coding for much of my career. I assure you that "young workers are preferred" is not at all the case. My favorite story is of a 50-something firmware engineer who told me that my previous job practiced "age discrimination" because he wasn't hired. I had to explain that the average age in the department was over 50 (I was 52 or 53 when he interviewed ...) and he wouldn't have been told oldest.

Comment: @JulieinAustin Was this in government? Because, I've found that government workforce in tech is very old.

Comment: @ConfusedDeer - No. In the world of embedded systems, hard real time, safety of life, etc. the workforce is VERY old. I'd be hesitant to hire anyone under 35 or 40 years old for a job where people could die if there was a bug. The upside of huge amounts of experience is the defect rates are extremely low and the "uptime" for a device is usually dependent on electricity. It's just an entirely different world than most of what goes on in the application and "consumer grade operating system" side of the industry.

Comment: @JulieinAustin I'll take a strict world over a sloppy one any day. The laziness of Developers that I've seen in the non-embedded workforce is unbelievable. I mean, easy code fixes that our code quality platform points out to them and can damn near tell them exactly how to fix it, yet still commit and try to do pull requests asking for their changes to be accepted. Can't wait until we actually enforce code quality gates that stop a pull request from even being created.

Comment: @ConfusedDeer - Yup. On most embedded projects a "warning" is treated like an actual error. Anyway, before we get admonished for "chatting" too much, I'll say farewell ;)